# Check Box using Google Closure

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

I retrieve a list of users from database and display it in a JSP. Each user has a status(Active or Inactive) associated with them and the status can be updated based on check-box selection on click of either activate or deactivate user. How do we render a check-box for each user dynamically using Google closure? And there must be a parent check-box which when checked all the other check-boxes will also be checked and all users can either be activated or deactivated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By 'dynamically' I assume you mean within the JavaScript? Google Closure doesn't run in JSP.

```
var users = [{ 'id': 'myId', 'activated': true }];
var usersLength = users.length;
var checkboxes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < usersLength; i++) {
    var user = users[i];

    var checkbox =
        goog.dom.createDom(
            goog.dom.TagName.INPUT, { 'type': 'checkbox', 'name': user.id });

    checkbox.checked = user.activated;

    checkboxes.push(checkbox);
}

var master = goog.dom.createDom(goog.dom.TagName.INPUT, { 'type': 'checkbox' });

goog.events.listen(
    master,
    goog.events.EventType.CLICK,
    function (event) {
        var isChecked = event.target.checked;
        goog.array.forEach(checkboxes, function(ck) { ck.checked = isChecked; });
    }
);
```

Comment: You need a "var user = users[i]" in the first loop somewhere I believe.